# For two inner products, can we find or proof a relation between them by a mathematical property?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, bilinear-form

I want to know if there is any method or property that can ensure a relation between two inner products; For example we have three vectors x, y, and z and we need to ensure the following relation :
$\langle x,y \rangle. \langle z,y \rangle =  \langle x,z \rangle$

Comment: Such an inner product certainly doesn't exist in all vector spaces. For example, as you can check, it will be impossible to construct an inner product with this property in any one dimensional vector space.

Comment: You say "two inner products", but in your question it looks like you're using the same inner product 3 times.  Would you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the condition to hold for *all* vectors $x,y,z$, then you're out of luck.

Specializing to $x=y=z$, the equation says $\langle x,x\rangle^2 = \langle x,x \rangle$. Since only the $0$ vector is allowed to have $\langle 0, 0 \rangle = 0$, this means that $\langle x,x \rangle = 1$ for *every* nonzero vector $x$.

I will leave it to you to show that this condition is not satisfiable (hint: consider $\langle \lambda x, \lambda x \rangle$ for some nonzero scalar $\lambda$).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The equation holds iff $x$ is orthogonal to $ \langle z, y \rangle y-z$.